# fopen, fprintf and fclose forces socket connection end

Tags: c++, networking, windows-8, windows-xp, dll-injection

I have a dll which hooks recv function of a network application. The code works just fine (it makes everything its suppossed to do), but if i add output logs to a file, the connection closes after some time working (the server side application throws the error "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host").

That time isnt even always the same, sometimes it closes almost when initializing connection, other times i can use the connection for few secs before it gets closed. It does not give any error or warning message. If i remove the log code, the application runs fine. Any idea why is that happening? I run it in windows 8 x64

Also, even erasing the log code, the connection keeps being closed in windows xp x32.

Here is the recv hook code:

```
int __stdcall NewRecv(SOCKET socket, char *data, int datalen, int flags) {
    int result = 0;
    if(!IsLoginServerPacket(&socket)) {

        INT size = 0,opcode = 0,temp = 0,writer = 0,second_op = 0;
        do {
            size = 0;
            second_op = 0;
            temp = 0;
            writer = 0;

            while(temp < 2) {
                temp += recvPacket(socket,recv_gs_buffer+writer,2 - temp,flags);
                writer += temp;
            }

            size = (*(SHORT*)recv_gs_buffer) & 0xffff;

            // THIS IS THE LOG CODE
            FILE *f = fopen("debug.txt", "a");
            fprintf(f, "datalen=%d, size=%d\n", datalen, size);
            fclose(f);

            while(temp < size) {
                temp += recvPacket(socket,recv_gs_buffer+writer,size - temp,flags);
                writer += temp;
            }

            Decrypt(&gs_crypt,recv_gs_buffer+2,size-2);
            opcode = (*(recv_gs_buffer+2) & 0xff);

            if(opcode == EXTENDED_PROTOCOL) {
                second_op = *(SHORT*)(recv_gs_buffer + 3);
                second_op &= 0xffff;
                HandleGameServerPacket(second_op,recv_gs_buffer+2,size-2);
            }
        } while(second_op == 0x8a || second_op == 0x8b);

        if(opcode == 0x00) {
            SetKey(recv_gs_buffer+4,&gs_crypt);
            SetKey(recv_gs_buffer+4,&client_crypt);
        } else
            Crypt(&client_crypt,recv_gs_buffer+2,size-2);

        int i = 0;
        while(i < size) {
            data[i] = recv_gs_buffer[i];
            i++;
        }
        //memcpy(data,recv_gs_buffer,size);
        result = size;
    } else
        result = recvPacket(socket,data,datalen,flags);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: One thing I notice is, that you pass in datalen, but then you write to `data[i]` using `size` as the blocklength, which is set to 0xffff.

Comment: yes, but the datalen param always has the value 16384, and the biggest packet sent by server isnt bigger than 300 bytes, so it should not overflow at all i think.

Comment: Is is possible that simply opening the file, writing to it, and closing it causes enough of a delay (perhaps sometimes?) to cause the application to think something is wrong (or to cause packets to be dropped, which in turn causes the application to be "unhappy"? Have you tried just opening the file at the start of day, and then writing without closing the file (or reducing the number of tiles file is opened/closed)?

Comment: yes, i tested so, but still has the same problem

Comment: I had the similar issue on vc++; in my case writing to the stream using printf was terminating the program between acquiring a semaphore and releasing it. Looks like context switch is missing something (either socket, shared memory or semaphore handler) while handling an interrupt. I was on vm (using one core).

Comment: You are looking at the wrong end of the wire for this problem.  It was the server that closed the socket, not the client.

Comment: so, is the server feeling a timeout or something like that?

Comment: Server is setted in non blocking mode, what could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem and its solution.

The injected app was configuring sockets on non blocking mode. Any little delay was making it throwing WSAEWOULDBLOCK (10035 error code). All i had to do to fix it was to retry the recv request if i get any error

```
INT val = 0;
while(temp < 2) {
    val = recvPacket(socket,recv_gs_buffer+writer,2 - temp,flags);
    if(val > 0) {
        temp += val;
                writer += temp;
    }
}
```

And

```
val = 0;
while(temp < size) {
    val = recvPacket(socket,recv_gs_buffer+writer,size - temp,flags);
    if(val > 0) {
        temp += val;
                writer += temp;
    }
}
```